# If a woodchuck could and would chuck wood, how much wood should a woodchuck chuck?

Tags: biology

I felt this was the place to discuss this question at length.

I have never fully got to the bottom of this riddle....

Lets assume, as the question states, that a woodchuck could chuck wood, and aforementioned woodchuck would (and will) chuck wood. The crux of the question remains - should a woodchuck chuck wood? What are the moral parameters of a woodchuck? Does the mere name of the woodchuck suggest that it would have grown up with a great deal of expectation placed upon it to chuck wood, thus creating a self-fullfilling prophecy? And if that's the case, should a woodchuck bow to this simple expectation, or defy the assumptions of others about his or her inclination to chuck wood?

Comment: recommend [Puzzling SE](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com) as a better place to post this.

Comment: Stack Exchange is **not** a forum, so discussion is right out. Worldbuilding is not a good fit for a question remotely related to this, discussion or not, because it appears to be asked purely in jest, and not as a serious question.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan I disagree.  Worldbuilding is the best fit for this question.  Since it asks about how a physical fenomena would behave if paramaters of the world was slightly different.  (This does not mean that I dissaprove of the closing, I would tend to agree with HDE226868 comment that OP is probably asking as a jest, and not out of any interest in knowing)

Comment: Wikipedia seems to have your answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_much_wood_would_a_woodchuck_chuck#Answers

Comment: @Taemyr I agree that it is a jest and not too serious, but note that OP did say "I have never fully got to the bottom of this riddle...."

Comment: @DJMethaneMan No, please don't post this question on Puzzling; it would be closed in an instant. Contrary to some people's belief, Puzzling does have quality standards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A woodchuck would chuck as much wood as a woodchuck could chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood

This would be about 362 cubic centimeters per day acording to an article in Annals of Improbable Research, 1995.

Comment: Citation needed?

Comment: @Lohoris Paskevich and Shea, Annals of Improbable Research, Volume 1, Issue 4, Jul/Aug 1995